# laravel print the error message for one input in the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I would like to print the error message for just the `value` input text field after the page redirecting from the controller.

I tried that

```
{{Form::text('value', '', array())}}
            <span class="errorMessage">
                <?php
                    echo $errors->first('value');
                ?>
            </span>
```

but I got empty results though I already redirected the request with the errors like this:

```
$input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, WaitingTimes::$rules);
        if($validation->passes()){

        }else{
            return Redirect::route('waitingtimes.create')->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
        }
```

#### Edit 1

I already tried $errors->has('value') but I also got nothing

#### Edit 2

```
public static $rules = array(
        'startTime' => 'required',
        'endTime' => 'required',
        'value' => 'required:integer'
    );
```

so as you see the value must be integer, but I entered string so there is absoltuly an error

Comment: Then there is no `error` for `value` field.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha no no there is error absolutly, that is why the pages is redirected.

Comment: Probably other errors but not for `value` field.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I made another edit to the question, could you check

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Okay I will print all errors and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
'value' => 'required:integer'
```

Should be:

```
'value' => 'required|integer'
```

Comment: See why you are my man? because you always help. Many thanks will accept it once the system allows +1

Comment: Oh! Glad to know that and you are welcome my dear :-)

Comment: May you help me here please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371759/laravel-loop-over-collection

Comment: yup :P, I wrote that comment when I asked that question :P

Comment: I need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396156/laravel-hasmake-keep-giving-a-different-results could you check please?