# laravel loop over collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this code:

```
$data = new Restaurant(array('id' => $restaurant_id));
        $data = $data->waitingtimes();
        foreach($data as $oneTime){
            echo $oneTime->value;
        }
exit;
```

as you see, I tried to print the `value` attribute for each `$data`, but I got empty results.

However, when I do this:

```
$data = new Restaurant(array('id' => $restaurant_id));
        $data = $data->waitingtimes();
        echo $data->first()->value; exit;
```

I get results, so the `$data` absolutely has values in it.

I tried to read the basecollection class documentation  here
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php

but there is nothing about loop.

I also read the conllection class documentation here http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Collection.html#5-73
but there is nothing about loop.

Comment: Hey? What you get in `$data` ? Try `dd($data)` and let me know about the output.

Comment: `$data` is a `Query` object, not a collection. `$data->first()` executes the SQL statement with `LIMIT 1` appended to it. You need to call `$data->get()` to get the actual results.

Comment: Then you need to use `get()`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha in `$data->first()->value` I got `55` which is the real value in my database, when I did `dd($data)` I got a very long results printed in the browser, do you want to give them to you?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Okay I will try it and update you.

Comment: I think it is an instance of `Query Builder`, is it ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I don't know :) really I tried to know from which class is this result, I thought it is from `Collection` that is why I started reading about collection and basecollection class

Comment: Right, it's a `QueryBuilder`.

Comment: What is `waitingtimes`, anyway ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha the `WaitingTime` is a model, while `waitingtimes` is the route. It refers to how much time a customer needs to wait before getting a response from our support time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `$data = $data->waitingtimes();` by

```
$data = $data->waitingtimes()->get();
```

Comment: yes that works, many thanks +1 will accept your answer once the system allows +1

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this:

```
$data = Restaurant::find($restaurant_id);
```

This will give you only one `Restaurant` by it's `id` and if `waitingtimes` is a relationship/related model then you may try this (known as `eager loading`, better than dynamic call):

```
$data = Restaurant::with('waitingtimes')->find($restaurant_id);
```

Then you may loop like:

```
foreach($data->waitingtimes as $waitingtime) {
    echo $waitingtime->value;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is a One To Many relationship. I will try your solution in another controller's function. +1 many thanks as always

Comment: Actually the `eager loading` saves you from `n+` query problem.

Comment: You are welcome but you may [read this](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: I am new to laravel and I haven't heard of this `eager_loading`. However, day by day I am learning more and once I need to use a `relation` queries, I will read it. Anyway, do you have any documentation for using the loop on the view please? I would like to loop over the some variables in my html view.

Comment: Check it on [templates](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures) in the `loops` section and if required then post another question with some relevant code.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent, Don't hesitate to accept other answer, it depends on you which one you need to accept and he answered first so you may accept his answer but follow `eager loading` to prevent so many queries.

Comment: Actually, I accepted the answer above because it was the first working answer and now I am so busy to read about `eager_loding`, I must finish this view today.

Answer (score 1):

replace $data = $data->waitingtimes(); by

$data = $data->waitingtimes()->get();