# laravel Hash::make keep giving a different results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to implement authentication in laravel 4

When the user registers, I hash the password and save it, like this:

```php
$password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
```

Then when the user tries to login, I want to authenticate him/her with the following code:

```php
if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')))))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

and that never succeeds. I tried to debug the code and it seems that the `Hash::make` function always gives a different result.

Am I using a good authentication methods?

Comment: Yes, `Hash` gives different results everytime. Use `Hash::check($plain, $hashed)` to compare. And like in the answer, don't use hasher in `Auth::attempt` method

Comment: Hash::make() ___will___ give different results every time you execute it, because it uses a different salt every time.... that's why it's more secure than hashing with a fixed salt.... that's why you have Hash::check() as well

Comment: @MarkBaker good information, thanks

Comment: @deczo did you meant the same as the first answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `Hash` the password you are giving to the `Auth::attempt` method, it should be like this:

```
Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')));
```

You may also check the password using `Hash::check('password', $hashedPassword)`. Read more about [security](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) on `Laravel` website.

Answer (score 3):

Do not hash the password in the auth::attempt() function the code should be like this:

```
Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')));
```

The auth::attempt() will hash the password and then check if it matches the one stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

To add some explanation to the answer, it is different every time because the hashing algorithm [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) generates a random string (salt) that has to be used to decrypt the password.

This is to protect passwords from rainbow table attacks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table